# Shuffle array values every time when page opened, no sessions ?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a database with some questions and I want every time the page is **opened**, *not refreshed* to show them in  different order.

The shuffling, it's ok :

```
 function shuffle_keys( &$array ) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);

    shuffle($keys);
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $new[$key] = $array[$key];
    }

    $array = $new;   
}
```

Shuffle the array with values from database and printing it:

```
shuffle_keys($array_questions); 
foreach( $array_questions as $key => $val ) {
    $key_value = ++$key;
    echo "<a href = '?id=$val'>".$key_value."</a> ";
}
```

Just now, when I refresh every time the shuffling is different I want it this way only when I first open the page.

Comment: you need to use session. HTTP is a stateless protocol

Comment: It would seem to me that your `shuffle_keys($array)` does exactly the same thing as `shuffle($array)`, only much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the same shuffling for the same session, (that's what I understood)

You can use a `$_SESSION` variable to store your array.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['array_questions']))
    $array_questions=$_SESSION['array_questions'];
else
{
shuffle_keys($array_questions); 
foreach( $array_questions as $key => $val ) {
    $key_value = ++$key;
    echo "<a href = '?id=$val'>".$key_value."</a> ";
}
 $_SESSION['array_questions']=$array_questions;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect a page refresh on its own. Perhaps consider setting a cookie and asserting whether it exists on page open?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static variable for the purpose. Just create a class as below:

```
class Base {

    protected static $variable = 0;
}

class child extends Base {

    function set() {

        self::$variable = 1; // let say 1 = 'sorted'
    }

    function show() {

    echo(self::$variable);
    }
}
```

Now when you enter your site,

Create an object and set the variable, calling the method

```
$c1 = new Child();
if($c1->show() == 0)
{
    // sort your array here and set the static flag to sorted(1)

    $c1->set();
}
```

Hope this help...

Comment: `static` does not persist across separate page loads!